# What calls the Apple store login view

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have setup in app purchases and I would like to display the apple store login page once the user decides to buy an item.

What calls or displays the alert/login view?

Is it build into the SKRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's built-in. The user will be asked for credentials when you add a new payment to the payment queue.

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if there are any items in the queue? interrupted purchases etc?

Comment: @Helium3 That would be the `transactions` property of SKPaymentQueue, which holds the currently pending transactions